# php code to get value from two textbox and display in i++ and j--

Tags: php, mysql

table -- **ctp**

column name =  **page1, page2**

i have two textbox in form with named  **textbox1, textbox2**

i am inserting **value 1 from textbox1 and 20 from textbox2**.

**i only need for loop which gets value from textbox1 and textbox2
and display textbox1 value incremented by +1 and textbox2 value  decremented by -1.**
and continue this upto value is reached on end.

- textbox1              textbox2
   1                       20
   2                       19
   3                       18
   4                        17
  like wise.....
  below is my code

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood correctly, if you have 2 text boxes:

```
Text box 1 has value 1
Text box 2 has value 20
```

and the PHP loop will show like:

```
textbox1 textbox2
1 20 2 19 3 18 4 17
```

PHP code:

Assuming 
$txt1 has Text box 1's value: 1
$txt2 has Text box 2's value: 20

```
  <?php
    $txt1 = 1;
    $txt2 = 20;
  ?>

  <?php for($i=$txt1; $i<=$txt2; $i++) { ?>

  <tr>                    
      <td class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $i; ?></td> 
      <td class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $txt2--; ?></td> 
  </tr>

  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: it is working exact what i want but , i need to select value in textbox1 and textbox2 from database. it is not hard coded.below is my code but is is not working properly..plz help me...                                                                   <?php    
$sqlpage = "SELECT * FROM ctp_pageno";             
$resultpage = mysql_query($sqlpage);                
if($rowpage = mysql_fetch_array($resultpage, MYSQL_ASSOC))
for($i=$txt1; $i<=$txt2; $i++)     {         
?> <?php } ?>

Comment: What does your result set return?